How to use ForEach activity with array iteratively in ADF pipeline
I have such pipeline:

In Script activity I am selecting list of IDs difference between two tables:

*SELECT id
 FROM a
where not exists (
    select * from b  where a.id= b.id
)*


In ForEach activity I have (Items = @activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows):
Set pipeline variable activity = activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].ID

Copy data activity = I can call API (several ids, separated by comma as well can be called as well), currently the requested body is like this:
@concat('{"id":[', '"', activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].id, '"', ']}')

I want the pipeline to iterate through the list that I am getting when select IDs. How can I achieve that? Currently, it is not working, and taking the same ID endless amount of times.

To use value from the Iterating array inside For-Each activity, you need to use item().id instead of activity('Script1').output.resultSets[0].rows[0].id expression.
So, the expression should be @concat('{"id":[','"',item().id, '"',']}') to achieve your requirement.
Here, I have given this expression in a string set variable for sample.

Result:


Now, you can see the IDs are changing inside For-Each as per the given array.
